# Можно ли говорить «отвлечь себя»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, глаголы, местоимения

Можно ли сказать «отвлечь себя», а не «отвлечься»? Если да, то в каких случаях?
В частности в таком предложении:

> Всю дорогу он пытался отвлечь брата и заодно самого себя.

Или надо говорить «и отвлечься сам»?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[ОТВЛЕ́ЧЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/908702), отвлеку, отвлечёшь, отвлекут, прош. вр. отвлёк, отвлекла, совер. (к отвлекать).
1. **кого-что**. Отклонить от чего-нибудь, направить на другое, заставить забыть что-нибудь. Отвлечь внимание. Отвлечь от дурных мыслей.

Отвлечь (кого?) себя — так можно говорить, все в пределах правил.
В указанном предложении такая форма, как мне кажется, понятна и предпочтительна.

*...Вот и было один раз, в таком состоянии колесования души, я **попробовал отвлечь себя** от боли записью каких-то слов народной речи* (М. М. Пришвин. Фацелия).

*Я не мог заговорить с нею иначе как на известную тему и **боялся отвлечь себя** от предпринятых целей каким-нибудь новым и неожиданным впечатлением* (Ф. М. Достоевский. Подросток).

*Он долго ворочался, накрывшись подушкой, **пытался отвлечь себя** сперва монотонным счетом, потом вдумчивой молитвой* (В. Ераносян. Бойня).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен (основное внимание уделено грамматическому анализу).

Можно сказать ***отвлечь себя***, например:

**Чтобы отвлечь** себя, раскрыл томик Маяковского, карманный, с которым никогда не расставался. [А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)]

**Анализ заданного предложения:**

Вариант (1). ***Всю дорогу он пытался отвлечь брата и заодно самого себя.***

Вариант (2). ***Всю дорогу он пытался отвлечь брата и заодно отвлечься сам.***

Вариант (2) легче читается и воспринимается, но он мне кажется не совсем корректным.

**Возможное редактирование:**

Всю дорогу он пытался отвлечь **брата** и заодно хотел отвлечься **сам**.

Или: Ему надо было отвлечь брата и отвлечься **самому**.

**Пояснение**

Из словаря:

1. САМ, I. местоим. сущ.
2. Указывает на лицо или предмет, которые **лично, непосредственно производят действие** или испытывают какое-л. состояние. ***Сам не знаю, в чём дело***. 2. Указывает на лицо или предмет, которые совершают действие **самостоятельно,** без постороннего вмешательства. Всё сделаю ***сам***. Уйду ***сам***, по собственному желанию.

**Вариативность** прочтения может придавать предложению стилистическую неточность, и это нужно исключить при его построении.

Значение (1) обычно используется, если **есть необходимость** в таком указании, например **успокоить кого-то и успокоиться самому,** при этом грамматика предложения должна ясно выражать эту семантику.

Рассмотрим заданное предложение: ***Всю дорогу он пытался отвлечь брата и заодно (пытался)  отвлечься сам.***

Вторая часть предложения (без повтора глагола и при наличии союза И) выглядит **самостоятельной**, поэтому нужное значение (1) не прочитывается ясно.

Comment: Когда я задавал вопрос об излишне подробных ответах, я как раз и имел в виду подобные. Да к тому же ваш ответ неправильный.

*>> В данном предложении возможен только один вариант: пытался отвлечь брата и себя* - это почему? Что, фраза автора неправильная?

Comment: У меня вызывает сомнение фраза "и отвлечься сам". Мне кажется. что надо говорить "отвлечься самому", а Вам как кажется? Например: "Он стал ласкать ее, чтобы отвлечь от пережитого страха и отвлечься самому". [В. Ф. Панова. Мальчик и девочка (1961)]

Comment: Вопрос очень прост.  **>> У меня вызывает сомнение фраза "и отвлечься сам". Мне кажется. что надо говорить "отвлечься самому", а Вам как кажется?** А мне не кажется. *Он пытался... заодно отвлечься самому*?! Перечитайте.

Это всё следствие того, что вы пытаетесь строить глубокие филоз-зофические построения из созерцания яичной скорлупы.

Comment: А уж про "разные смысловые оттенки".. тут и вовсе слов нет. Это заслуживает не одного минуса, а трех.

Comment: Обсуждения не по сути вопроса прошу вести в чате, но не в комментариях. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/

Comment: А я и говорю, что  фраза "отвлечься сам" неверна, а "отвлечься самому" в это предложение не подходит.  Если хотите  что-то доказать, то доказывайте теоретически или с помощью практических примеров из художественной литературы.

Comment: "Отвлечься сам" вполне подходит (если нет, то тут нужны о-очень серьезные возражения, а не "примеры из художественной литературы", которые подходят в последнюю очередь. Вы и правила постановки тире будете сверять по Горькому?)

Comment: Я не считаю. что этот вопрос простой, что он, как вы сказали, "выведенного яйца не стоит". Этот вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: Конечно, если вы пытаетесь обсуждать то, чего в вопросе и в помине нет (скажем, отвлечься сам или самому?), то "проблемы" будут расти, как снежный ком. Но это вы придумываете проблемы, а вопрос-то простейший.

Comment: Про вопрос Вы уже всё сказали: простой, простейший и т.д. Но я не вижу Вашего ответа, Вы же можете дать еще  один ответ, правильно оформленный и обоснованный. Найдите в литературе это выражение -  "отвлечься сам".

Comment: Зачем? Ответ был дан, и ответ совершенно правильный (и вы его прочитали), но по "правилам" он не подходит. Если владельцы сайта (или модераторы, или кто там еще) заинтересованы в том, чтобы посетители сайта получали нормальные ответы, - они примут нормальные правила. Но на это надежды мало, ибо сами авторы "правил" не слишком грамотны. Чего стоит одно обращение: "Мы обращаемся к вам *по поводу вашей учетной записи*" - к вам с таким не обращались? Смесь русского с пиджином, но им это слух не режет.

Comment: Не уходите в сторону от проблемы. Вот такой вариант я могу придумать: Он не мог отвлечься сам, ему требовалась чья-то помощь. Но в вопросе ведь совсем не такая ситуация.

Comment: Автор вопроса не просил ничего придумывать, верно? А тогда зачем? Именно - совсем не такая ситуация, а вы от первоначальной фразы не оставили почти ничего. Еще раз вопрос: зачем?

Comment: У автора в выделенном тексте стопроцентно корректная фраза. Стопроцентно! Так надо было и ответить (и я как раз так и ответил). Вы же развели дискуссию на пустом месте.

Comment: Спасибо за беседу, у меня вопросов больше нет. Ваш "совершенно и стопроцентно правильный ответ" удалили, но будем надеяться, что ответит кто-нибудь еще.

Comment: Нет, зачем... Наоборот, поставят плюсы единственному оставшемуся ответу. За длину. У вас нет вопросов, но у меня есть: "объект обычно указывается" - это лично вам так кажется?